# How to skip video in cypress to a certain time

Tags: cypress

I have a page in VueJS that holds a video. I'm trying to test the scenario where when the video is skipped to a certain second, it makes an HTTP request.

I'm having issues with currently jumping to a certain point in time in the video.

In a normal JS environment I could do:

```
const video = document.querySelector('video')

video.currentTime = 30
```

Now, in Cypress it looks like we need to do things a little different since my attempts are not working.

So far I have tried the following:

```
cy.dataCy('project-session-view__video').then(($video) => {
   // @ts-ignore
   $video[0].currentTime = 20

   console.log($video[0].currentTime)
})
```

But the video is not being skipped to 20 seconds. I have tried to

```
$video[0].currentTime = 20000
```

but the video keeps getting rewinding to the beginning instead of jumping to 20 seconds.

How can I skip a video to `X` seconds in cypress?